# How do I set properties for my custom UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to set labels/buttons/images for a custom UICollectionViewCell that is being used as a sticky header.

These are my classes.

1. ParlaxController
2. CollectionViewCell
3. AlwaysOnTop
4. AlwaysOnTop.xib

-AlwaysOnTop inherits from CollectionViewCell. In this class, I am setting properties and methods for the sticky header of my UICollectionView. 
-CollectionViewCell is for each individual collection cell.
-ParalaxController is where I set up my CollectionView delegate/datasource and manipulate my data.

My question. From my manipulated data in ParalaxController, how do I set this data to images and labels that I have connected to my AlwaysOnTop classes? I also have buttons in my xib that need to manipulate data in my Paralax Controller.

Thanks.

Comment: you are kind of asking for a wide ranging tutorial here. suggest you run through a tutorial like http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12 , then maybe come back with a more focused question

Answer (score 1):

I needed to use viewForSupplmentryElementOfKind method like so.

```
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if ([kind isEqualToString:CSStickyHeaderParallaxHeader]) {
        AlwaysOnTop *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:kind
                                                                            withReuseIdentifier:@"header"
                                                                                   forIndexPath:indexPath];
        UIImage *albumArt = [UIImage imageNamed:@"noAlbumArt.png"];
        cell.albumArt.image = albumArt;

        return cell;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Here I can update the header's view with data from my controller.